# How to deploy a JavaFX project with Maven to an EXE?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, ant

I hope this question does not seem to basic but I could not find any good documentation despite researching for hours.

I use Maven (Version 3.3.9) for my JavaFX (Version 11.0.2) with JDK 13.0.1 project and want to build an EXE.
What is the easiest way to do this?

All my researchs stucked somewhere.

Following [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html), I tried to integrate ant-tasks. But the documentation required `ant-javafx.jar` to be in the `jdk_home/lib` directory which doesn't make sense for JDK 13 since it doesn't come with JavaFX.

But this was the latest official documentation where I could find something about Ant Task. So I guessed Ant Task does not work for JDK13 anymore, am I wrong? I hope this does not seem like a dumb assumption but I could not find a newer documentation.

I have also tried the [zenjava plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) but the latest commit is 2 years ago, and when I try to use it I get an error

> Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1/../lib/ant-javafx.jar

Since I've read that `javafx-packager` was renamed to `java-packager` a longer time ago (sorry, don't remember, where I've read this) I assumed that zenjava is not up to date for JDK 13.

I couldn't find anything else.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to upgrade your Java and JavaFX versions to 14. Then you can use the new jpackage tool, which does exactly what you need. How to do all this with Maven is described in this tutorial, which I did together with Dirk Lemmermann. Maybe that helps.
[JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX)

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know where to find further documentation? I tried your sample project and it worked. But for my own project it unfortunatelly doesn't work so I need a place where I can get more information to find possible reasons for that. I can create and install the msi and exe without any errors but when I want to open my application it says "failerd to run JVM".

Comment: Further documentation of what? There is of course the official documentation for all the used tools. According to my experience problems like this are mostly caused by the fact that the app is now running outside of the IDE and so, e.g., resources are not found inside jars if they are not accessed correctly. Therefore I use a script to run the app outside of the IDE before I do the full packaging. It is easier to spot errors this way.

Comment: yes. I somehow couldn't find the official docs. Neither per google nor searching on the java homepage