# How to easily deploy a JavaFX project in 2021?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javafx, deployment, executable-jar

Every tutorial I found on the internet was about creating a JavaFX artifact and building it, including [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html#troubleshoot) one from JetBrains. It says, that for JDK 9+ this way won't work anymore.

Comment: have you tried the [link to the workaround](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular) JB included in the linked article? Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772873/how-to-deploy-a-javafx-project-with-maven-to-an-exe

Comment: Or did you search for jpackage which is the tool of choice here?